# How to filter ComboBox values in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

In a .NET winforms application, how can I filter the data in my 2nd `ComboBox` with respect to the value selected in my 1st `ComboBox`?

Comment: We need to know if this is even web or windows :)

Comment: Combo box filter on windows form

In one form i got two combo boxes in which values are coming from two different tables.
I want to make it such that if a user selects item from the first combo box
it filters the values and shows only relavent ones in the second combo box.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming WinForms:

```
combo2.DataSource = ((IEnumerable<string>)c.DataSource)
    .Where(x => x == (string)combo1.SelectedValue);
```

Of course you might need to replace `IEnumerable<string>` with `IEnumerable<YOURTYPE>`.

Answer (score 0):

very cryptic question - however, if you are using webforms, you may want to try using the AutoPostback property on the combobox. You can then capture the combobox onChange event and place your filtering code there.

Answer (score 0):

You just fill the second combobox in the *selectedindexchanged* event of the first combobox. Quite easy, I have done it lots of times.